# SQLite / C API - Closing a database - Is there an official documentation error?

Tags: c, sqlite

In the official SQLite's C API documentation ([www](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_close)) for an API call `sqlite3_close()` I can read this:

> ### Closing A Database Connection
>
> ```
> int sqlite3_close(sqlite3*); 
> int sqlite3_close_v2(sqlite3*);
> ```
>
> The `sqlite3_close()` and `sqlite3_close_v2()` 
>   routines are destructors for the `sqlite3` object. Calls to
>   `sqlite3_close()` and `sqlite3_close_v2()` return `SQLITE_OK` if the `sqlite3`
>   object is successfully destroyed and all associated resources are
>   deallocated.
>
> If the database connection is associated with unfinalized prepared
>   statements or unfinished `sqlite3_backup` objects then `sqlite3_close()`
>   will leave the database connection open and return `SQLITE_BUSY`.

How can these two functions with a return value `int` return a string `SQLITE_OK` and `SQLITE_BUSY`? This is impossible. Where can I catch the strings that functions are returning? I was thinking of using `sqlite3_errmsg()` ([www](https://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_errcode)) like this:

```
do{
    sqlite3_close(my_db);
}
while(strcmp(sqlite3_errmsg(my_db),"SQLITE_BUSY") == 0);
```

This results in a lot of API calls which would probably stress the database. Does anyone have any better solution?

Comment: SQLITE_OK is a macro from the sqlite header which would in all logic be an int

Comment: So you comparison would be `sqlite3_close(my_db)==SQLITE_OK `

Comment: I understand. So both functions return an `int` representation of a `SQLITE_OK` or `SQLITE_BUSY`.

Comment: Somewhere in `sqlite3.h` is a line like `#define SQLITE_OK 0`. I don't know why you think it's a string... nothing in the documentation suggests that. See https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html for all the possible error codes.